# Is object that calls performSelector:withObject:afterDelay get retained by the NSRunLoop?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsobject, nsrunloop

I have a certain object that perform a "Refresh" every X seconds. ("The Updater")
The way I'm doing this repetitive update is by calling `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` and in my selector I'm re-scheduling as necessary.

Of course I have a method to stop these invokations by calling `cancelPreviousPerformRequests`.

The problem is that this "Updater" is never being deallocated.
There is only one other object that retaining the Updater (AFAIK), and the retaining object **is** being deallocated and calls `[self setUpdater:nil];`

I'm suspecting that this is have something to do with the `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` method, but I couldn't find any reference to that question in the documentation.

Can anyone confirm or dismiss it?

Thanks!

**APPENDIX**
This are the scheduling methods:

```
-(void) scheduleProgressUpdate
{
    [self stopProgressUpdates]; // To prevent double scheduling
    [self performSelector:@selector(updateProgress) 
               withObject:nil 
               afterDelay:1.0];
}

-(void) updateProgress
{
    // Perform update..
    [self scheduleProgressUpdate];
}

-(void) stopProgressUpdates
{
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self 
                                             selector:@selector(updateProgress) 
                                               object:nil];
}
```

Comment: As far as I know the `performSelector` method retain its receiver and arguments.

Comment: That should be an answer, not a comment...

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the performSelector method retain its receiver and arguments.

Comment: For now I'm just upvoting, once I'll confirm it or you'll supply a link that confirms it I will also accept the answer